# Ubuntu wont boot, Grub error, will boot repair mess with windows boot files?

Tags: boot, grub2

Now, I removed Ubuntu completely from my PC (since it was installed before using Wubi Installer). And re-installed it the old fashion way. Installation was smooth no problems at all except, when I rebooted to boot ubuntu for the first time, it did not boot and showed an error and saying GRUB Rescue > 
What shall I do now ?!
I searched google and found out about boot repair. The thing is, will it mess my windows ?! Or does repair Ubuntu and linux distributions only ?!

Comment: It adds a grub boot loader that will allow you to boot windows

Comment: Windows boots fine, Ubuntu is not booting at all

Comment: It finds all partitions that have operating systems, creates a menu of them and you will then be able to boot both, used boot-repair a few times its a life saver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to reinstall grub.
use boot-repair. it is easy to use. go on live ubuntu and the install boot-repair. open boot-repair and go to recommended repair. one thing, you have to write down the link showed before reboot message.

Comment: Thanks for the help I used boot repair and it worked fine, just had to update grub through the terminal since the boot menu did not show windows.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of boot repair, but I might have a working solution for you.

1. Get a live USB and boot into the system.
2. Find out which partition is Ubuntu. You can do this via running disk utility (palimpsest in terminal). Then click on your harddisk and select your ubuntu partition. Write down the device, for example: "/dev/sda5".
3. Open a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) and mount the ubuntu partition:

   `sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt`
4. Install grub on your ubuntu partition:

   `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda`

The command above assumes your hardrive device is /dev/sda, so it will install the grub bootloader on the harddrive. If everything goes well, grub will try to find all the operating systems located on your computer. After that you should be able to reboot and see a normal grub menu. Good luck!

Comment: boot-repair is "preferred" as it is a graphical tool. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair